# Is there a way to optimize/speed-up a piece of code related to finding a path in network - NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have directed network in the model. I have different type of breed of agents that are chosing the optimal path on the network. All the agents during the set up get the current node (where they are created) and the target node (where they need to move), and they need to find the shortest path between them. I did that with this piece of code:

```
breed [crossing crossings]
directed-link-breed [channel channels]
breed [ship ships]

....

to add-ships
  let j 0
  foreach list-of-ships [
  num-of-ships ->
   create-ships num-of-ships [
     set type j
     set origin-node one-of crossings
     move-to origin-node
     set target-node one-of crossings


     ;; set the path variables
     let target-n target-node
     ask origin-node [ set temporary-path nw:weighted-path-to target-n  "travel_time" ]   ;; set the path to go
     set path-to-go temporary-path
     set path-to-return reverse  path-to-go    ;; set path to return
   ]  
  j j + 1
]
end
```

When I added this line of the code inside the loop (another loop)  `ask origin-node [ set temporary-path nw:weighted-path-to target-n  "travel_time" ]`  i bumped into memory issue. Is there is another, more optimal, way to set a path?

PS: I know this line is working correctly, I tested it.